# Adding fields to a Rails model without saving them in the database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I am rendering a view based on a JSON object representing a Rails model.  This JSON object needs fields that are not part of the Rails model, so I'm adding them in the controller as follows in Example 1:

```
#Controller
events = Event.where(<query>).each do |event|
    event[:duration] = (event.end - event.start)/3600
    event[:datatime] = event.start.hour + event.start.min/60.0
    ...
end

render json: events
```

This renders my data correctly.  However, I get the following deprecation warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute `duration'. Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. Please just use `attr_writer` etc.
```

I want to rewrite my code to avoid this warning.  If I try treating these extra fields as a standard object attribute, the values are not rendered correctly.  Below is my attempt to change to using standard object attributes:

```
#Controller
events = Event.where(<query>).each do |event|
    event.duration = (event.end - event.start)/3600
    event.datatime = event.start.hour + event.start.min/60.0
    ...
end

render json: events



#Model
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::AttributeMethods
  attr_accessor :duration, :datatime
```

This causes the fields to be filled with `undefined`.  This is true if I use `attr_writer` instead of `attr_accessor`.  How can I fix this problem?  Am I forced to store these temporary attributes in the database or am I just using the wrong syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to read and write the accessors use `attr_accessor`:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :duration, :datatime
end
```

You do not need to include `ActiveModel::AttributeMethods` to utilize `attr_accessor`.

To include the accessors in the JSON tell render to include them:

```
render json: events, methods: [:duration, :datatime]
```

Comment: As I said, using `attr_accessor` also makes the values undefined.